# Wrong file ordering in MySQL Docker image with Debian as base

Tags: debian, files, sort

My problem is relatively simple as I try to make a migration with the help of the Flyway CLI.

The problem here is, that the system orders the migration files in the wrong order and my new file isn't viewed as the newest version. The files have the same version as the POM so we know in which version which changes came.

The current version is 1.4.11 but it's viewed as an older version.

`V1_4_11.001` should be newer than `V1_4_7.001`

Why is that and how can I fix it without using the outOfOrder flag? The exact same files are in the right order on my MacBook.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 staff  226 Oct 18 16:02 V1_1_0__patch.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 staff 3174 Oct 18 16:02 V1_2_0__patch.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 staff 1774 Oct 18 16:02 V1_2_2__patch.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 staff  130 Oct 18 16:02 V1_4_0.001__merge_skill_level_godlike.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 staff  111 Oct 18 16:02 V1_4_0.002__modify_publications.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 staff 2149 Oct 18 16:02 V1_4_0.003__create_v_competence_by_experience.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 staff   55 Oct 18 16:02 V1_4_11.001__add_profile_updated_on.sql  // Newest version
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 staff  712 Oct 18 16:02 V1_4_7.001__add_duration.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ls` sorts its output according to a ["lexicographical" sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47478926/12231187) of the filenames. In that order, `V1_4_11` comes after `V1_4_1` and before `V1_4_2` etc.

Since you are using Debian, there is a flag `-v` to `ls` that should do what you want:

> `-v`    natural sort of (version) numbers within text

E.g. if I create empty text files based on your example, the "normal" output order is:

```
myuser@myhost:~$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_1_0__patch.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_2_0__patch.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_2_2__patch.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_4_0.001__merge_skill_level_godlike.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_4_0.002__modify_publications.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_4_0.003__create_v_competence_by_experience.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_4_11.001__add_profile_updated_on.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_4_7.001__add_duration.sql
```

If I use the `-v` flag, it gets:

```
myuser@myhost:~$ ls -lv
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_1_0__patch.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_2_0__patch.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_2_2__patch.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_4_0.001__merge_skill_level_godlike.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_4_0.002__modify_publications.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_4_0.003__create_v_competence_by_experience.sql  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_4_7.001__add_duration.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Okt 19 00:47 V1_4_11.001__add_profile_updated_on.sql
```

**However**, please note that this is really only the order in which the `ls` command outputs the files; it has nothing to do with how the files are internally organized on the file system. Also, you should not try to [parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) in order to identify the latest file; if that is the ultimate goal, there are other ways to do this (but it would depend on which shell you are using and what exactly it is you want to do).